# Is it possible to show my rep/flair while being anonymous?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flair, anonymous

What to do when someone wants to show his flair/rep and at the same time do not want his identity to be known?

I thought for a second for an intermediate site to produce a certified/anonymous flair.

Comment: Just checking that I understood correctly: You want your SE account name to be unknown to viewers of your flair?

Comment: Yes. I also want the employer/viewer to know I am not making this up and picking others' flair.

Comment: But why do you need flair then?

Comment: To show that I am reaching out/ involving in the community. This is important when it comes to academics.

Comment: @Xline *You* are? You can choose the flair of any user then... No one can tell thats you anyway.

Comment: I really don't get what you are looking for - the flair is an image. If you want to, download it and post it on your site without anything linking back to your profile. It won't update, but you can do that manually. I don't see the point of anonymizing it given that you want to show it is yours...

Comment: If you find a way to do this, I'm going to use an anonymized Jon Skeet flair.

Comment: 8 down voters lol. didn't think the idea was *that* bad.

Comment: For that to work, I think that there would need to exist a system that lets you generate an anonymous "proof of reputation" that is signed by StackExchange and - to prove that this is a certificate issued for your employer - contains some challenge that the employer gave you. The real point is IMHO - would that really be that useful to other users? And also - wouldn't this spoil the game in any way for the others?

Answer (score 6):

Flair is not some secure proof of your rep. It's a picture. Anyone can get anyone's flair. The only way to gain real world benefit from your SE activities is to make a connection between the two, such as telling people "I am [username] on StackExchange." If you're not willing to do that, then you can't gain a real world benefit from what [username] has done.

As a thought experiment, let's say SE came up with a way for you to prove that you own an account with Xk rep where X is a multiple of 10, along with dozens of badges. What problem would it solve or what purpose would it serve? None. Even for the simple case of SO, surely I care what tags you earned that rep in, and whether your earned it from asking or answering. Surely I want to look at a handful of your answers to see whether you're a good writer, good example-inventor, good explainer, or just write clever code. Hearing that someone has 20k rep doesn't really tell you much if you don't know which of the 20k rep users they are.

(Yes, there are some counter examples. Once you make the first page or two of all time users on a site, it can be argued you know your way around the entire subject matter of that site pretty well. But such people can just state "my [site].stackexchange.com account is in the top 100 out of a million users for reputation" and don't need some automated certified anonymous flairy thing - they can just type the sentence.)

I would recommend you connect your SE identity to your real world identity in some way, such as linking to your SE accounts from your blog. If it's important to stay totally anonymous on SE, then I recommend you abandon a plan to gain real world benefit from the numerical rep and the more nebulous "reputation and impression" you've built up here.

Also, I think you're overestimating the value of "proof". In an interview, on a resume, in a cover letter, or on a social media profile, you can tell people that you keep up to date in your field by reading blogs (and naming 3 or 4 high profile bloggers you claim to read) or by taking courses, and naming a course provider such as Pluralsight. You can claim to have founded a user group or attended a conference. People don't ask you to attach some sort of digital proof of these activities. Similarly you can say you're active on [site] and have rep of over [whatever] and they are unlikely to ask for proof. Sure, you may get tripped up by an interviewer who asks "did you take [specific course]?" and knows it well (for example I once asked this about a course I wrote and delivered at Pluralsight) and can tell from your answer and reaction that you actually didn't take it. The SE equivalent might be asking if you're enjoying a particular review queue that you in fact don't have access to yet at the claimed rep. Being able to answer these questions correctly, because you do have the rep and you are that active, will be better than any kind of digital proof that some unknown account has a particular rep and badge count.

Answer (score 3):

Like the commenters, I'm not sure I see the purpose of this. It sounds like you want to hold some anonymized badge that proves you to have millions and billions (or so) of rep points on one or several SE sites, but how would that even prove anything?

**[image: profile for Xline at Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A for meta-discussion of the Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites]**

There's your flair. I could pass that off to an employer/viewer as being my own. All anonymization aside, this doesn't count as proof of anything. If it were to be anonymized, that would simply make it less reliable. I could post Jon Skeet's with the name redacted and claim it my own.

On top of those challenges, I'd wonder why you even want to do this. We tend to put a lot of (okay, maybe not *a lot*) weight on rep points 'round these parts, but most people in the real world probably don't. You'd be much better to advertise the content you've put on various sites, than just the fact that people appreciated you for it. And anonymizing it would take even more away from that.

Comment: Take this scenario: you want people/employer to know that you are active in online communities of your field. At the same time, you do NOT want them to know who you are. The easiest answer: do not tell them in first place. I am looking for a second answer where one could stay anonymous and tell.

Comment: @Xline Sure, but that's what I mean: a flair won't tell them one way or the other that you're active, even in the form we have now. It proves that *a user* has *an amount of reputation*. You could take anyone's flair and claim it as your own, and you wouldn't even have to be a member of the Stack Exchange community to do that. Even if you *had to be you* to get your flair, someone, somewhere, would screenshot it and that would be that. The only way to prove your presence is to link to your profile with your name, anything else could be extremely easily forged.